# Showing that an Algebra is not a $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

In a script I found the following example for an algebra, which is not a $\sigma$-algebra:
Let
$$\mathcal{I} = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ (a, b] : -\infty < a < b < \infty \} \cup \{ (-\infty, b] : b \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ (a, \infty) : a \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all finite pairwise disjoint unions from $\mathcal{I}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Showing that it is an Algebra is straight forward. But I cannot find a way to show that it is not a $\sigma$-Algebra.

Comment: $\{0\}=\cap_n (-\frac 1 n,0]$

Comment: Thanks. I did not think about that property. It's because for $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ the $A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$ and therefore $(\bigcup_{i \geq 1} A_i^c)^c = \bigcap_{i \geq 1} A_i \in \mathcal{A]$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that makes the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ be $\sigma$-algebra is that for each $\{A_j\} \in \mathcal{A}$ then $\cup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now, consider the collection $\{(a-\frac{1}{j},b]\}_{j=1}^\infty \in \mathcal A $. Then we can simply see that

$$(a-\frac{1}{j},b]^c = (-\infty,a-\frac{1}{j}] \cup (b,\infty),$$

then

$$
\cup_{j=1}^\infty( (-\infty,a-\frac{1}{j}] \cup(b,\infty))=\cup_{j=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{j},b]^c = (\cap_{j=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{j},b])^c
=[a,b]^c \not \in \mathcal{A}$$

Then

$$ \cup_{j=1}^\infty( (-\infty,a-\frac{1}{j}] \cup(b,\infty))=\cup_{j=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{j},b]^c \not \in \mathcal{A}$$

So we showed that there is a family of sets in $\mathcal A$ , namely, $((-\infty,a-\frac{1}{j}] \cup(b,\infty))^c$ and its union is not in $\mathcal A$. Then $\mathcal A$ is not $\sigma$ algebra.